# Confine the directories in which a script will act

Tags: shell-script, cd-command

For example I have a script looks like:

```
for i in */*/
do  
 cd $i
 cp POSCAR.ideal OSZICAR ..
 cd ..
 rm -r */
 cd ../;
done
```

to remove subfolder of a folder, however with a bit of uncautious, for example, the last `../` is miswritten as `../../`, then the whole computer will be erased. Which is extremely bad! So I want to ask is there a method to safely confine the operation range of a terminal so that such tragedy does not appear?

Comment: `man find `; avoid insecure `cd` in loops -- try to use full paths; use "echo rm ..." before  " rm"; use "rm -i" to confirm; don' t  root accounts on Fridays...

Comment: Like @JJoao says, a script like this is dangerous at best. It needs a lot of error testing and more complete paths to be remotely safe. And, I don't even want to think about what could happen if some of your directory/subdirectory names have spaces in them since the variables aren't quoted! I've never used it, but there is a chroot command that would help, but rewriting the script would be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Joe has correctly mentioned in the comment, it is best to rewrite such a dangerous script. However, if you do wish to go ahead with your current script, a rudimentary method is to wrap all your `rm` operations within `if` conditions.

So, for example:

```shell
if pwd | grep <some-pattern>; 
then rm -r */; 
fi;
```

You can modify the `grep` part according to your needs. My point is that just do a simple `grep` verification before issuing the `rm` command.